# Not able to create locked CMS layout while plugin installation time

Tags: symfony, shopware

I'm trying to create a locked CMS layout while installing the plugin, but it's not creating a locked layout.
Here is the code,

```
$page = [
        [
            'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
            'type' => 'page',
            'name' => 'Test',
            'locked' => 1,
            'sections' => [
                [
                    'id' => Uuid::randomHex(),
                    'type' => 'default',
                    'locked' => 1,
                    'position' => 0,
                    'blocks' => [
                        [
                            'locked' => 1,
                            'position' => 0,
                            'type' => 'image-cover',
                            'slots' => [
                                ['type' => 'image', 'locked' => 1, 'slot' => 'image']
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Is that the code from your `upsert`-call? It's bit unclear what you are doing. Did you check the database, whether the locked flag is set?

Comment: It's fixed for me. There is no field like "locked" in the cmc_page definition. I've to use a direct query for it.

Comment: Please share more details. The code you've shown does nothing else than defining an array

Comment: @NicoHaase It's fixed for me. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear that `cms_page` doesn't has `locked` property, but there is only a database column to set the locked layout. So you need to add it while migration or alter the table after creating a particular layout.